# get the error 'Authentication credentials were not provided' even after passing the token in the headers

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, jwt, django-rest-framework-jwt, django-rest-knox

### UPDATE

i just added this to my settings.py:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':  (
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication', **<--THIS!**
    'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
),
    }
```

now i get this when i'm trying to get user with a token:

"detail": "Invalid username/password."

but i'm not trying to sign in, only get a user with a token.

### THE ORIGINAL QUESTION

Im trying to get all the todos that created by the user api/todo, and get the user api/auth/user.. but I keep getting this error:

```
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}
```

in the frontend I'm sending the headers (tried both in the body, in query, nothing is working)

```
const config = {headers: {Authorization: `Token ${token}`}}
```

so I tried in postman, in Headers tab to send the token - Authorization:Token fcabd79eb8f0954d9d29d48059ab38853c7f79c582aa2653a16b4b9e176b0225

and i get the same error.

here is my service at the frontend

```
async function query() {
    try {
        // tried both this: 
        return await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${types.TODO_API}/`,{headers : config.headers});        
        // and this: 
        return await axios.get(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/${types.TODO_API}/`, null, {headers : config.headers});
    } catch (err) {
        throw err;
    };
};
```

here is my setting.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'rest_framework',
    'corsheaders',
    'todo',
    'user',
    'knox'
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES':  (
        'knox.auth.TokenAuthentication',
    ),
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ),
}
```

here is the TodoViewSet

```
class TodoViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated, )
    serializer_class = TodoSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.todo.all()

    def preform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner = self.request.user)
```

here is the GetUserView

```
class GetUserView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticated,)
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

    def get_user(self):
        return self.request.user
```

Comment: don't know your API, but usually it's `Authorization: Bearer ${token}` and sometimes `Authorization: JWT ${token}` (you added a JWT tag, but your token as shown above is not JWT)

Comment: thx for the comment, this type of token can be access like this 'Token ${token}', but unfortunately its not working both from frontend and postman